# Build test with Maven doesn't run through on an other maschine

Tags: spring, maven, osgi

I have a spring-osgi-application which I develop on a 32-bit machine. There I can build my bundles without any problem with (example: mvn clean package).

I got a new machine, a intel 64-bit machine and there the tests doesn't run though. It can't find the autowired dependencies (beans) from the other bundles which are mocked.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.yourtools.athene.store.AtheneStore] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
... 34 more
```

What could I check?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe there are some cached artifacts on your old machine that make your build work. Delete (well, move away) everything in ~/.m2/repository on your old machine, maybe then the old machine will fail too. In that case you'd know that has nothing to do with the machine.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I deleted the maven repository on the old machine and now it isn't working on there too..

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like spring is looking for a Bean "org.yourtools.athene.store.AtheneStore" and can't find an implementation. As you said your program doesn't compile on the first machine either if you clean your local maven repository you are most probably missing a dependency in your pom.xml.

Find the corresponding jar, add it as a dependency and everything should be fine.